# Using multiple Ultrasonic sensors as counter

Tags: arduino

I am working on a small project which is using multiple ultrasonic sensors to detect a movement object and count it(such as a car). I use switch case but the program is not going to the all cases, therefor it is not working properly and the counter is not increase either decrease. i tested each sensor and realized they are worked. but I don`t know why i cant get a result with this code , if you help me i appreciated in advance ... below is my code

```
     const int sensorNum = 2;

uint8_t reading_0;
uint8_t reading_1 ;



int sensing[sensorNum][2];

unsigned long duration = 0; //period between transmit time and receive time in microSeconds
float distance = 0.00;      //distance in centimeter
const float fixedDistance = 30.00;
const float vilocity = 0.034;   //Vilocity of ultrasonic waves = 340 m/Sec = 0.034 cm/uSec
//const float cmDivisor = 29.4118;

float reading = 0.00;
int carCounter =200;
int PCarCounter=0;
int capacity = 200;
//int activate = LOW;
uint8_t current_ENTERstate = 0;

const uint8_t RESET = 0,CAR_START2EN=1,CAR_ENTERING=2,CAR_EN1=3,CAR_ENTERED=4;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for(int i = 0; i<sensorNum; i++){

    sensing[i][1]=LOW;
    sensing[i][2]=LOW;
    pinMode(i+2,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(i+2,LOW);
    pinMode(i+8,INPUT);
    digitalWrite(i+8,LOW);
    current_ENTERstate = 0;

  }
}


//==============================================================




void loop()
{
    for(int l=0; l<2; l++){

          reading_0 = calcDistance(2,8);
          reading_1 = calcDistance(3,9);

              if(reading_0 > 30.0 && reading_0 < 200.0) {
                sensing[0][l] = HIGH;
              }else if(reading_0 < 30.0 || reading_0 > 200.0) {
                sensing[0][l] = LOW;

              } 
              if(reading_1 > 30.0 && reading_1 < 200.0) {
                sensing[1][l] = HIGH;
              }else if(reading_1 < 30.0 || reading_1 > 200.0){
                sensing[1][l] = LOW;

              } 

    }
switch(current_ENTERstate){  

      case RESET:
        if(sensing[0][0]||sensing[0][1]){

          current_ENTERstate = CAR_START2EN;



          break;
        }else{
          current_ENTERstate = RESET;
          break;
        }
        break;
      case CAR_START2EN:
        if( sensing[0][0]||sensing[0][1] && sensing[1][0]||sensing[1][1] ){
          current_ENTERstate = CAR_ENTERING;
          break;
        }else{
           current_ENTERstate = RESET;
          break;   
        }
        break ;
      case CAR_ENTERING:
        if(  sensing[1][0]||sensing[1][1] ){

           current_ENTERstate = CAR_EN1;

          break;
        }else{
           current_ENTERstate = CAR_START2EN;
          break;
        }
      case CAR_EN1:
        if( sensing[0][0]==LOW && sensing[0][1]==LOW && sensing[1][0]== LOW && sensing[1][1]==LOW ){
           current_ENTERstate = CAR_ENTERED;

          break;
          }else{
           current_ENTERstate = CAR_ENTERING;
          break;
          }
     case CAR_ENTERED:
          carCounter++;
          break;

     default: RESET;     
  }       // switch end

}
//====================================================================================

float calcDistance(int trigger, int echoPin){


    digitalWrite(trigger,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigger, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigger,LOW);

    duration = pulseIn(echoPin,HIGH,40000);
    distance = vilocity * duration / 2.0;

 //Serial.print(distance);
  return distance;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `l` as a variable name. It makes code like `sensing[1][l]` tricky to follow.

Comment: its just an (L) letter and nothing more .

Comment: `default: RESET; ` ?

Comment: It is much more: every time I see a `1` I have to look twice to see if it's an `l` and vice-versa.

Comment: ok bro , sorry next time i will not do like that

Comment: In `if( sensing[0][0]||sensing[0][1] && sensing[1][0]||sensing[1][1] )` do you realise that `&&` takes precedence over `||`?

Comment: The easiest way to test this is to build the build with a stub for `calcDistance()` that provides the expected sequence of measurements, and then set through the code in a debugger.  If you want debugging assistance you would do well to describe the algorithm and how you expect it to work and how it actually works.  Even without a debugger, some simple trace-debug prints to the console will help.

Comment: This is not C, but likely Arduino.

Comment: What @WeatherVane says.  Also from a practical point of view you would do well to add some hysteresis between HIGH and LOW switching, because sensors are generally "noisy"; for example while it must be >30.0 to go HIGH,  you might require it to fall below say 28.0 to go LOW.  In principle you do have some tiny hysteresis because when the value is *exactly* 30.0 you do not change the state, but being floating point that is an unlikely situation.

Comment: You have not elaborated on what it should do and what it *does* do, only stating that it does not enter *all* the states; you have provides less diagnostic information than that available to you and expect a diagnosis.

Comment: Having every `case` statement executed is entirely dependant on the logic within those `case` statements that change the state, which is where I previously pointed out a possible error in your logic. So I suggest you re-examine them, and put (brackets) round anything you are unsure of, to force the logic to behave the way you want it to, since I don't know if Arduino has different precedence rules.

Comment: @KarzanA.Raza : Whose comment are you referring to that you cannot understand?  It is difficult to provide detail in the comments.  I will post an answer in the hope that it is in fact a solution, but the reason for the comments is that it is not yet clear what your problem is.

Comment: @WeatherVane : Arduino "Sketches" are essentially C++ (so the order of precedence is the same as C), a framework is provided so that you define two functions `setup()` and `loop()`, and the Ardunio executive calls `setup()` once and `loop()` repeatedly. The environment takes care of details such a linking the necessary libraries etc. but the code is ultimately compiled as C++ using GCC for AVR.

Answer (score 2):

The following is suspicious (credit to @WeatherVane for spotting it):

```
if( sensing[0][0]||sensing[0][1] && sensing[1][0]||sensing[1][1] )
```

Because `&&` is evaluated *before* `||`The conditional expression is evaluated as if it were written:

```
a = sensing[0][1] && sensing[1][0] ;
if( sensing[0][0] || a || sensing[1][1] )
```

which seems unlikely to be the intention.  It should probably be written thus:

```
if( (sensing[0][0] || sensing[0][1]) && 
    (sensing[1][0] || sensing[1][1]) )
```

(line break added for clarity).

With respect to the sensing, you should add some hysteresis when reading noisy sensors. To avoid repeating a great deal of high-maintenance code it would be better to define a function

```
void distanceHighLow( float reading, int& sensing ) ;
{
    static const float HYSTERESIS = 2.0f ;
    static const float MIN_DISTANCE = 30.0f ;
    static const float MAX_DISTANCE = 200.0f ;

    if( reading > MIN_DISTANCE && 
        reading < MAX_DISTANCE ) 
    {
        sensing = HIGH;
    }
    else if( reading < (MIN_DISTANCE - HYSTERESIS) || 
             reading > MAX_DISTANCE + HYSTERESIS) 
    {
        sensing = LOW;
    } 
}
```

Then you call this function thus:

```
distanceHighLow( reading_0, sensing[0][l] ) ;
distanceHighLow( reading_1, sensing[1][l] ) ;
```